# QueryBuilder Symfony2, 10 last results in ASC

Tags: symfony, query-builder

My Query with QueryBuilder:

```
 <?php    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')  
                   ->join('m.sender', 's')
                   ->join('m.target', 't')
                               ->addSelect('s')
                   ->addSelect('t')
                   ->where('(m.sender = '.$Myid.'OR m.target = '.$Myid.')')
                   ->andWhere('m.grouper ='.$groupe) 
                   ->orderBy('m.created_date', 'ASC')
                   ->setMaxResults('10');

                   return $qb->getQuery()
                   ->getResult();
```

How to display the last 10 results in ASC?
thank you

Answer (score 6):

From Doctrine's documentation:

> **15.2.3. Limiting the Result**
>
> To limit a result the query builder has some methods in common with the Query object which can be retrieved from `EntityManager#createQuery()`.
>
> ```php
>     <?php
>     // $qb instanceof QueryBuilder
>     $offset = (int)$_GET['offset'];
>     $limit = (int)$_GET['limit'];
>
>     $qb->add('select', 'u')
>        ->add('from', 'User u')
>        ->add('orderBy', 'u.name ASC')
>        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
>        ->setMaxResults( $limit );
> ```

As you can see, you have to use `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()`.

---

I suggest you to look the chapter dealing about the QueryBuilder in order to **avoid your ugly parameters concatenations**...

Comment: I have used array_reverse, it's more simple solution.